# OracleConnectinStringBuilder does not allow to set 'Connection Timeout'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Why OracleConnectinStringBuilder does not allow to set 'Connection Timeout', any hints?, or any direct way to set it?

Edit : When I pass connection string containing 'Connection Timeout', it throws exception, saying - ' Keyword not supported: 'connection timeout'.
(using .net framework 2.0)

```
string connstring = "Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=180;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size8;Decr Pool Size=5;";

OracleConnectionStringBuilder b = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(connstring);
```

Comment: Please share the connection string or code you are using.

Comment: just for info, I observed that - OracleConnectionStringBuilder has become obsolete now

Comment: The code you have edited in does not fail on `Connection Timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it using the property like this:

```
public int ConnectionTimeout{get; set;}
```

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleConnectionStringBuilderClass.htm#CHDHHHBH):

> This property specifies the value corresponding to the Connection
>   Timeout attribute in the ConnectionString property.

Comment: this property does not exist for OracleConnectionStringbuilder object.

Comment: OP uses a connection string to fill the `OracleConnectionStringBuilder`. Also, with the `Connection Timeout` property specified it does work. It does not need to set the property by hand.

Comment: I think, I am using the older version of oracle.dataaccess.dll, and that is the reason I am not able to get it right. Thanks for your help guys.